# Basic information about sybase

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I have knowledge of sql-server but i am trying to learn Sybase, I need some basic help in that, please ignore if my questions are too silly.

1. Where can i get this database (sybase) for practice, I went on the official site, but it asks me to fill lot of details, is it changeable ?

2.Can you please suggest a basic book for this?

1. How different is it form SQL-Server?

Comment: thanks For voting it down...I believe people voted down are expert in everything from the day they were born...

Comment: https://www.sap.com/campaign/ne/sybase/ase_express_edition_linux/index.epx?kNtBzmUK9zU  - You will have to fill out information, but that's no different than most other RDMBS vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For a free product it's the least you can do to fill in a form
2. No. I learnt from online help.
3. SQL Server was actually built from Sybase many years ago back at version 6.0 (maybe 25 years ago) but has now of course branched off. You'll find a lot of the functions are the same.